# Web API beside ASMX in the same project?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx, asp.net-web-api

I have some web services in a asp.net web application using `asmx`.

as it goes I need to provide more web services here and I'm going to use Web API instead of traditional asmx.

the question is, Can I have these to types of web service in the same project which is going to deploy on the same web host?

here is the solution explorer:

[image: solution explorer]

as you can see, the `CNIS.asmx` and `Webservise_TCIKH.asmx` are serving from long time ago, and now I need to add more web services using Web API, but the old web services should remain functional .

I've added a new API controller called `AirKindController.cs` in the folder called CNISAPI. this is the implementation:

```
public class AirKindController : ApiController
{
    CNISDataContext db;
    private AirKindController()
    {
        db = new CNISDataContext();
    }
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<AirKind> Get()
    {
        return db.AirKinds;
    }
```

BUT, when I request the `http://localhost:3031/CNISAPI/api/AirKind`  or `http://localhost:3031/api/AirKind` there is an error of 404! Am I calling right? or it is not possible to have these two types of web services in the same place?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: (solution)**

by  @moarboilerplate guidance, I've added a `Global.asax` to my project and add the route configuration in the `Application_Start` method like below:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
```

the `WebApiConfig.Register` is here:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Now I'm able to get the xml formatted output by requesting `http://localhost:3031/api/AirKind`.

Problem SOLVED!!!

Comment: You need to configure the route/s for your API controller/s when your application starts up. If you're doing that, can you post your config code?

Comment: Also yes, you can do this.

Comment: I doesn't have any route in my solution, the project template was the old asp.net 3.5. I just add the ApiController class . how to do it?

Comment: in the global.asax, I add this: protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            **HttpConfiguration config=new HttpConfiguration();**

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }   it is not work so far!

Comment: Thanks @moarboilerplate, it is Solved! my above code addition was incorrect! I've added the solution in the **EDIT** section of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this problem is solved in the question itself, I decide to add the answer in the Answers section:

by  @moarboilerplate guidance, I've added a Global.asax to my project and add the route configuration in the `Application_Start` method like below:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
```

the `WebApiConfig.Register` is here:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Now I'm able to get the xml formatted output by requesting `http://localhost:3031/api/AirKind`.

Special thanks to @moarboilerplate .